# How do I detect if my application isn't committing transactions?

Tags: python, mysql, transactions

I'm using the [MySQL Python Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/)

At the beginning of all requests, I take a database connection from the connection pool. At the end of all requests, I commit the connection to ensure that no uncommitted transactions are inadvertently lost. However, I would like to find these uncommitted transactions in an automated way, so that they can be properly committed in their more appropriate place.

Is there a way for [Connection.commit()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) (or a related function) to somehow report if anything was actually committed? If there was, I can set up some monitoring to track these events and slowly resolve them over time.

Comment: Could you just enable autocommit? `cnx.autocommit = True`

Comment: @BeRT2me I don't want autocommit, because I have discrete transactions that I need to manage. Eg: inserting 2 rows into 2 different tables atomically.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Always run with autocommit turned on.  This is sufficient for some types of applications, but does not make use of "transactions".  This is not wise, for example, for a "bank" application.  It is probably OK for casual applications where there won't be multiple connections competing for resources.  Or apps that won't be seriously hurt if the server crashes in the middle of a run.

Plan B:  Be religious about always explicitly using Start and Commit.

Plan C:  Mix A and B.  Leave autocommit ON, but sometimes use Start and Commit.  This gives you the security of B (when needed), together with the simplicity of A (the rest of the time).

Plan D:  DO NOT USE THIS!  Turn autocommit OFF and hope to remember to specify `COMMIT` eventually.  This seems to be the case you are in.

(PS: This applies for all apps, not just Python.)

Comment: Autocommit is a non-starter for me, as I need transactions in my application. I just wish there was a way to ask the database server if there are pending transactions for the connection.

Comment: @argmi - When I need transactions, I think about what to have in them.  With that, I think about where to put the `START` and the `COMMIT`.  That way, I never forget to `COMMIT`.

Comment: That's helpful advice for a new code base, but this is a large existing code base :) I am attempting to find all of those places to put START and COMMIT by tracking which incoming requests result in uncommitted transactions.

Comment: Extra `COMMITs` won't hurt.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but my question is how to find uncommitted transactions at the end of a request. I appreciate you offering "how I would solve a related problem", but it is not what I am asking.

Comment: Sorry, I should have started by saying:  "I don't know how to find all uncommitted transactions."

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your feedback. Cheers.